# Changing SQL server compatibility Level

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, compatibility

I have a database which was upgraded from 2000 to 2005. Is there any issue using sp_dbcmptlevel to change compatibility level to 90. Will this cause any issues with old queries or stored procedures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you run the SQL Server upgrade adviser on the old database?  It will tell you if there is any obvious problems.  Be sure to test on a development database.

Here is the tool

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1470e86b-7e05-4322-a677-95ab44f12d75&displaylang=en